# JavaScript function does not work with webbrowser.document.body.innerhtml

Tags: c#-4.0, webbrowser-control

I'm using a web browser for showing some data.

When I change my web browser control content with this code:

```
webbrowser.document.body.innerhtml=htmlbody;
```

My JavaScript function does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the solution
i put the j query function in body and my problem solved:D

Answer (score 0):

I believe that changing `innerHTML` in that way breaks up the DOM, so the JavaScript will not function any more.

I had the same problem. If you are trying to make changes to the body, the easiest way I found would be through injecting JavaScript into your page, without changing the HTML in this way.